# Prove sequence converges to zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There are two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ and I know that their multiplication $(a_n b_n)$ converges to 0.
Let there be a constant $c>0$ that for almost every $n$, $b_n\geq c$.
I need to prove that $(a_n)$ converges to 0.
I wanted to use the squeeze theorem, and I have that $c a_n\leq a_n b_n$
But I can't think of something equalto or smaller than $a_n$?

Comment: Side Remark: Do you mean series or sequence?

Comment: so $\sum b_n$ is a divergent series then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b_n>c$  for almost all $n$. Then 
$$|a_n|=\left|\frac{a_nb_n}{b_n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{c}|a_nb_n|$$ for $n$ large enough. Since $a_nb_n\to0$ we have that $|a_nb_n|\to0$, and this squeezes $|a_n|\to0$.